# 2 Homeservers 2 Domains possibel?

Tags: dns, dyndns

i have a homeserver with nextcloud which is running fine.
i got a domain (domain.com) registered and my homeserver uses ddclient to update the dns settings of the domain.

now i am working on another project with a raspberry pie which also should have a domain.
i already changed the listening ports of the raspberry apache2 to e.g. 8090 and got the port forwarded correctly.

when i open domain.com:8090 it redirects me to my raspberry instead of my homeserver which is nice.

Now....How can i get domain2.com go to my raspberry? it always leads to my homeserver :(
Did i missed some settings?

**Solved**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://192.168.2.108:80/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.2.108:80/
<Location />
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If the homeserver is always running, you can setup a reverse proxy on its web server to forward requests to your raspberry

Comment: That's what i was missing, thanks a lot :)